# Why is $rs->RowCount not returning a value?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, ado

I'm using a basic SQL query with ADO and PHP but the row count always returns -1.  What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
include 'constants.php';

// Create an instance of the  ADO connection object
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection")
    or die("Cannot start ADO");

// Open the connection to the database
$conn->open(DB_CONN_STR);

$query = "select * from table_name";

$rs = $conn->execute($query);

if (!$rs) {
    return;
}
else {
    return $rs->RecordCount();
}
```

I know this table has values...what am I missing?

Comment: Where is the code from the execute function and the code of RecordCount(); this is the only place where it could go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual says why.
http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#recordcount

seems you have set

> $ADODB_COUNTRECS = false

Comment: Is this something I need to enable server side for mssql?

Comment: I've never used adodb, but it sounds like a library config option based on the way they explain the get a count when the driver doesn't support it(buffering all the rows in).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Adodb with PHP, with a PDO mssql driver.

- I executed a SQL query with `GetOne` or `LimitQuery` in a try / catch block
- the query resulted in an error
- i caught the exception and went on to execute a valid query with `Execute`
- the resulting calls to `RecordCount` would wrongly return `-1` (but i could iterate on the rows).

I found out that some Adodb functions set that `$ADODB_COUNTRECS` flag to `false` before executing their query. In case of an error the flag was not set back to `true`, and that is why `RecordCount` returned `-1`.

I set the global variable to `true` in my exception constructor and that solved the problem.